# Взломали сайт, помогите найти дыру в защите

Tags: администрирование, ssl, хостинг, защита, взлом

Доброго времени суток!

Я администрирую сайты у нас в компании.
Недавно **нам взломали сайт, и не один**. **Атакам ежедневно подвергаются все сайты, находящиеся на хостинге**. Выглядит это как добавление php файлов, архивов и целых папок в корни сайтов и в директории типа images.
Результатами взлома сначала являлась подмена главной страницы для роботов гугл, затем 2 рассылки с нашего почтового сервера и рассылка со ссылкой на нехороший файл на одном из наших сайтов.

**Что было сделано:**

1. Почистили все от вредоносного кода, обновили cms основного нашего сайта, так как сначала думали, что только он был взломан, запретили доступ к системным папкам по другим ip.
2. Поменяли все пароли (к ftp, cms, бд). 
   Дальнейшие действия не очевидны. Наш хостер не дает изолировать друг от друга папки на хостинге, как и не может ограничить доступ к ftp по другим ip(

**Какой следующий шаг?**

**UPD 4.12.17**

3. Установили на всех сайтах логи доступа.
4. Прогнали сайты через ai-bolit, появилась почва для размышления и поле для деятельности.
5. После вычистки и настройки сайтов будем их разносить по разным хостингам и наблюдать.

**UPD 18.12.17**

6. На прошлой неделе выложил на хостинг чистые копии сайтов. Ограничил доступы к системным папкам и отключил register_globals через .htaccess.
7. С тех пор проблемы со взломом не возникали. Скоро будем переезжать на новый хостинг.

Спасибо всем за помощь. С наступающим вас!

Comment: CMS случайно не WP/Joomla ? SSL и хостер не даст ничего (0,1% вероятности, что сломали хостера)

Comment: Извините, понимаю вашу боль -- но на сайте обсуждаются конкретные вопросы, а ваш слишком некоренкретен. Чтобы советовать что-то конкретное -- нужно знать, что у вас конкретно есть, а без этого все советы будут слишком общими (хотите один? чаще всего ломают через ftp, поэтому общий совет -- переходить на схемы деплоя без заливки файлов по ftp -- может и вам поможет рекомендация). Всю конкретику вы всё равно не скажете -- поэтому общарайтесь в специализированные фирмы за консультацией/аудитом, там помогут.

Comment: @Alexey Shatrov нет, 1 сайт на modx revo. Еще один сайт на переписанном WP. Еще 2 без cms, на css.
@A K я Вас понял. Спасибо за совет. Просмотрели все логи FTP - несанкционированных заходов нет.
Обратимся в фирму. Кстати, можете кого-то посоветовать?

Comment: могу точно на 101% сказать, что дыры в WP! и не просто дыры, а ДЫРИЩААА. Удаляйте эту недоcms пока вас не удалили очередным php скриптом.

Comment: @Антон, прежде чем обращаться сделайте так - разнесите сайты на отдельные аккаунты.

Comment: @Антон - очень советую https://revisium.com/ru/clean/?pro=2736451 это авторы известного ai-bolit

Comment: Обмазаться логами вдоль и поперёк и по ним выглядывать, кто откуда куда лезет. Дальнейшие действия по результатам чтения логов

Comment: @Alexey Shatrov на счет разнесения сайтов - в процессе. Через ай болит прогнали сайт - оказалось есть над чем поработать) PHPmailer обновляю.

Comment: @A K спасибо, записал.

Comment: @andreymal уже)

Comment: Я бы присоединился к тому, что WP дыряв, но справедливости ради могу сказать, что сам WP ещё вполне ничё по сравнению с другими движками. Но вот когда на на WP начинают ставить левые плагины -- это становится не просто дырищей, а просто помойкой. Выносить его на отдельный аккаунт.

Comment: @Антон, у вас остался сайт на wp либо вообще какие-то сайты с вирусами? Делаю утилиту для чистки wp (ai-bolit есть, да, но хочу написать что-то свое), а вот базы вирусов не хватает. Сообщество, отнеситесь с пониманием.

Comment: @DaemonHK Да, что-то осталось. Весь сайт не скину, но пару файлов плохих смогу наскрести.

Comment: @Антон контакты в моем профиле

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать перекрыть вот этот вектор атаки:

> Выглядит это как добавление php файлов, архивов и целых папок в корни сайтов и в директории типа images.

Но для этого необходима возможность создавать на сервере новых пользователей и настраивать веб-сервер, т.е. эта инструкция - не для шаред-хостинга.

---

**1.** Разделяем пользователя-владельца сайта и пользователя от которого работает веб-сервер. Второму пользователю запрещается доступ на запись во все директории кроме тех куда пользователи могут загружать файлы.

В UNIX-подобных ОС без использования ACL такого поведения можно достигнуть включив обоих пользователей в одну группу, далее первый пользователь делается владельцем файлов и директорий, и права на файлы устанавливаются 640 (740 на директории или 750 если важен листинг директории).

**2.** В тех директориях, куда разрешается загрузка пользовательских файлов - запрещаем запуск любых скриптов на уровне веб-сервера.

В Apache для этого надо прописать примерно следующее (только изучите свой конфиг чтобы увидеть реальные типы возможных скриптов - ну или выключите все что не используете):

```
<Directory "/.../upload">
    RemoveHandler .php .phtml .php3
    RemoveType .php .phtml .php3
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Также конфиг выше отключает поддержку .htaccess в этих директориях, потому что в противном случае при наличии дыр злоумышленник может загрузить этот файл и разрешить самому себе запускать скрипты.

При использовании Nginx надо закрыть директории со статикой от поиска в них скриптов через использование `^~`:

```
location ^~ /uploads/ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Также в случае использования сайтом паттерна Front Controller можно отказаться от популярного `location ~* \.php(/|$)` в пользу непосредственного направления нужных маршрутов на фронт-контроллер (да, для этого придется внимательно изучать используемую CMS):

```
location / {
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/index.php;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $uri;
}
```

Если у вас внезапно Windows и IIS - надо убрать все обработчики кроме статических файлов и заблокировать конфигурацию от изменений:

```
<location path="uploads" overrideMode="Deny">
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Важно сделать это именно через location в файле более высокого уровня, чтобы злоумышленник не мог обойти ограничение через замену файла web.config в доступной для записи папке.

**3.** После закрытия папок куда пользователи могут загружать файлы от загрузки туда серверных скриптов надо закрыть их от загрузки html-страниц. Это уже атака не на ваш сервер, а на ваших пользователей - но это же не означает что от нее не надо защищаться?

В Apache это делается через `RemoveType .html` (полный список типов уточните в своем конфиге), в nginx надо будет явно перечислить разрешенные к загрузке типы файлов (`types { ... }`), а в IIS это делается настройкой `system.webServer/staticContent` по аналогии со списком обработчиков (там можно как удалить несколько типов так и полностью составить список с нуля).

---

Если веб-сервер настроен правильно - то злоумышленнику будет намного труднее пользоваться имеющимися дырами. А дыр связанных с загрузкой пользовательских файлов можно будет и вовсе не бояться.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду пробовать)